Feet/sitting on table with Torah books - size and shape of table
I understand that it is forbidden to put one's feet on a table that has Torah books. Does the size and shape of the table make any difference?
For example, regarding shape: a curved desk, that is smoothly connected, but conceptually separated into two parts - may one put one's feet on one part of there are Torah books only on the other part?

Or regarding size: if a table is very long, and the Torah books are on one end, and far from reach or mind, can one put one's feet up on the other end?
